# Laravel do I have to worry about mass assignment when setting field by field

Tags: laravel, mass-assignment

I am a bit confused when it comes to laravels mass assignment.

I know that I can protect fields using:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password'
    ];
```

and be protected here:

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(Input:all);

or

$flight->fill(['name' => 'Flight 22']);
```

But I **only** create or update Models like this:

```
public function createUser(NewUserRequest $request, User $newUser)
    {

$newUser->insertUser($request);

}
```

**insertUser** looks like this:

```
public function insertUser($request)
    {
        $newUser = $this;
        $newUser->user_type = (int) $request->input('user_type');
        $newUser->username = $request->input('username');
        $newUser->email = $request->input('email');
        if ($request->filled('password')) {
            $newUser->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        }
        if ($request->filled('facebook_id')) {
            $newUser->facebook_id = $request->input('facebook_id');
        }
        $newUser->save();

        return $newUser;
    }
```

As you can see I always pick what fields I want to insert and what data should be inserted. So do I really need to set my `$fillable` when I dont use the `create()` or `fill()` methods?

Comment: no you can do it your way without setting that.

Comment: @Jeff just to double check. Do I only need to worry about ``$fillable`` when I use some of the two functions ``create()`` and ``fill()`` or is there more "auto fill" functions in Laravel?

Comment: anytime you set attributes with an array, it checks it against `$guarded` or `$fillable`. so `updateOrCreate`, `firstOrNew`, etc also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose of mass assignment protection is to protect developers who source model properties direct from user input, for example:

```
Example::create($request->input());
```

Without mass assignment protection a user who knows about the underlying application architecture could inject values into fields they're not expected to have access to, e.g if your User field has an `is_admin` value they could change their `is_admin` to `1` instead of `0`.

Mass assignment protection is *only* required when working with unsanitized user input and mass assignment protection is only enabled by default when mass assigning. You have 3 options for a secure application:

1. Make use of mass assignment and whitelist each property in `$fillable`
2. Assign values individually so there is no mass assignment protection, e.g: `$user->name = 'John Doe'`
3. Disable mass assignment protection and do not mass assign from user input, e.g:

   ```
   protected $guarded = [];

   Example::create($request->only('name', 'age'));

   Example::create(['name' => $request->name, 'age' => $request->age]);
   ```

You do not need need to disable mass assignment protection in your example because you are not mass assigning values, you're assigning a value to each property individually. You can determine if you are using mass assignment by asking yourself "Am I passing in an array of properties and their values?".

You can learn more about mass assignment in the [Eloquent documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: This is basically what I suspected, thanks for the clarification and the peace of mind.